# nginx rewrite for an url with parameters

Tags: url, url-rewriting, nginx

I have two types of URL and want to rewrite it for friendly URL.

**1. The first:**

```
https://example.com/folder/myfile.php?id=xx&param1=yy
```

I want to rewrite to:

```
https://example.com/folder/myfile/xx/yy
```

**2. The second:**

```
https://example.com/another-folder/myfile.php?id=xx&param1=yy
```

I want it rewrite to:

```
https://example.com/myfile/xx/yy
```

Please help me how to do it. I've searched Google but I do not understand the principle rewrite.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this in your `location / { }` block:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /myfile.php?$args =404;
rewrite ^/folder/myfile/(.*)$ /folder/myfile.php?id=$1&param1=$2;
```